# Create a condition for legend in ggsurvplot

Tags: r

At the moment, the legend is Quartile 4. HR 0.62 (95%CI 0.10-3.72), P=0.60.

I would like to create a condition when as follow: if P-value is >=0.95, I would like to write `Quartile 4. P=0.99.` So without the HR and the 95% CI.

HR and Ci make nonsense writing like this for now.

With this code:

```
#libraries
library(readxl)
library(tidyverse)
library(tidytidbits)
library(survivalAnalysis)
library(dplyr)
library(survival)
library(survminer)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)
library(ggpubr)

df$quantile <- df$delta_mon1_baseline_to_d3

#define quartile
df$Quartile <- findInterval(df$quantile, quantile(df$quantile, na.rm = TRUE)[-5])

#factor Quartile
df$Quartile <- factor(df$Quartile)

#cox regression
cox <- coxph(Surv(mace_months_date_vs_date_sample, mace) ~ Quartile, data = df)

# create the tags
coxP <- data.frame(summary(cox)$coefficients)[,5]
coxConf <- data.frame(summary(cox)$conf.int) %>% 
  rownames_to_column() %>% 
  mutate(p = coxP,
         p2 = case_when(       # determine direction
           round(p, 3) > p ~ '=',
           round(p, 3) < p ~ '=',
           round(p, 3) == p ~ '='
         ),
         p3 = ifelse(round(p, 2) == 1, T, F), # id if p value is 1 (too high!)
         # gsub adds space, round, keep trailing zeros
         tag = paste0(rowname %>% gsub("(\\D)(\\d)", "\\1 \\2", .), 
                      ". HR ", exp.coef. %>% sprintf(fmt = "%.2f", .),
                      " (95% CI ",
                      lower..95 %>% sprintf(fmt = "%.2f", .),
                      "-", upper..95 %>% sprintf(fmt = "%.2f", .),
                      "), P", p2, "",
                      ifelse(p3,
                             yes = "0.99",    # if p rounded = 1
                             no = sprintf(fmt = "%.2f", p)))) %>% 
  select(tag)

# validate as expected
coxConf
```

I have got this legend in the graph

[image]

Here are my data:

```
      ID age     sex  mace mace_months_date_vs_date_sample trop egfr  dm smoke  delta_mon1_baseline_to_d3
 1    44 52        1     1                              30 2600  56    1     0                       -822.  
 2    32 66        1     0                              73 1710  90    1     0                       -562.  
 3    20 56        1     1                               5 NA    75    0     1                       -502.  
 4    17 44        1     0                              77 840   71    0     0                       -389.  
 5    52 49        1     0                              74 1740  71    0     1                       -372.  
 6    57 58        1     0                              74 5010  68    0     1                       -308.  
 7    79 68        1     0                              45 776   90    0     0                       -284.  
 8    14 74        1     1                               6 7120  78    0     0                       -279.  
 9   223 63        1     0                              46 4281  90    0     0                       -218.  
10    56 43        1     0                              70 1360  90    1     0                       -173.  
11    50 54        1     0                              70 15300 90    0     1                       -163.  
12    31 47        0     0                              72 6490  77    1     1                        -95.7 
13    35 47        1     0                              77 NA    83    0     0                        -71.0 
14    36 64        1     1                               5 15940 52    0     1                        -69.7 
15    15 65        1     1                              43 6300  49    1     0                        -69.6 
16    12 57        1     0                              71 6020  88    0     1                        -66.5 
17    43 59        0     0                              74 2100  84    0     1                        -58.8 
18    22 46        1     0                              77 5330  88    0     1                        -29.3 
19    54 59        1     0                              71 1500  81    1     1                        -25.7 
20    26 66        1     0                              77 500   51    0     0                        -12.5 
21    29 73        0     0                              77 NA    51    0     0                         -2.99
22    25 54        1     0                              73 1080  87    0     0                          2.81
23    39 54        1     0                              74 990   77    0     0                         32.9 
24    47 62        1     0                              69 1420  85    0     0                         33.0 
25    49 54        1     1                              28 NA    76    1     0                         44.1 
26    24 47        1     0                              77 2390  90    0     1                         47.7 
27    45 51        0     0                              73 3710  65    0     1                         55.9 
28    30 73        0     0                              68 3340  48    1     1                        117.  
29    16 57        1     0                              73 180   99    0     1                        131.  
30    55 47        1     0                              70 NA    90    0     1                        131.  
31    37 81        1     0                              74 NA    99    1     1                        147.  
32    21 46        1     0                              75 3600  87    0     1                        153.  
33    60 72        1     0                              76 470   62    0     0                        160.  
34    18 56        1     0                              69 6390  90    0     1                        165.  
35    13 53        1     0                              69 1970  87    1     1                        180.  
36    19 66        1     0                              78 9320  59    0     0                        180.  
37    33 59        1     0                              69 2260  79    0     1                        193.  
38   139 39        0     0                              58 NA    90    0     1                        209.  
39    38 55        1     0                              78 3930  90    1     0                        244.  
40    27 28        1     0                              71 6440  90    0     1                        248.  
41    58 36        1     0                              76 NA    78    1     1                        327.  
42    61 48        1     0                              76 4470  90    0     1                        336.  
43    42 38        1     0                              69 1800  69    0     1                        375.  
44    28 76        1     0                              71 40    90    1     1                        419.
```

Here is the console output:

```
structure(list(ID = c(44L, 32L, 20L, 17L, 52L, 57L, 79L, 14L, 
223L, 56L, 50L, 31L, 35L, 36L, 15L, 12L, 43L, 22L, 54L, 26L, 
29L, 25L, 39L, 47L, 49L, 24L, 45L, 30L, 16L, 55L, 37L, 21L, 60L, 
18L, 13L, 19L, 33L, 139L, 38L, 27L, 58L, 61L, 42L, 28L, 121L, 
192L, 120L, 68L, 41L, 23L, 216L, 136L, 88L, 87L, 182L, 93L, 154L, 
94L, 116L, 145L, 228L, 76L, 63L, 59L, 219L, 175L, 164L, 181L, 
234L, 146L, 242L, 71L, 67L, 187L, 128L, 151L, 215L, 132L, 173L, 
124L, 119L, 224L, 140L, 221L, 172L, 115L, 103L, 73L, 194L, 106L, 
193L, 148L, 156L, 203L, 100L, 81L, 190L, 206L, 233L, 189L, 105L, 
220L, 85L, 11L, 205L, 131L, 1L, 225L, 183L, 213L, 7L, 147L, 134L, 
86L, 69L, 212L, 199L, 75L, 137L, 191L, 245L, 111L, 153L, 112L, 
89L, 243L, 109L, 165L, 95L, 231L, 5L, 168L, 159L, 6L, 179L, 77L, 
155L, 171L, 174L, 84L, 102L, 207L, 230L, 138L, 188L, 241L, 72L, 
235L, 211L, 127L, 237L, 70L, 210L, 110L, 133L, 2L, 218L, 180L, 
229L, 65L, 130L, 96L, 226L, 152L, 197L, 178L, 141L, 195L, 92L, 
162L, 201L, 217L, 222L, 208L, 104L, 160L, 66L, 74L, 185L, 177L, 
123L, 184L, 204L, 227L, 125L, 83L, 8L, 143L, 9L, 3L, 117L, 10L, 
198L, 244L, 108L, 34L, 214L, 4L, 97L, 200L, 113L, 80L, 166L, 
98L, 238L, 239L, 114L, 167L, 64L, 157L, 90L, 149L, 129L, 170L, 
91L, 135L, 122L, 240L, 99L, 236L, 144L, 53L, 176L, 107L, 232L, 
163L, 142L, 118L, 126L, 158L, 186L, 82L, 78L, 48L, 62L, 209L, 
196L, 46L, 150L, 161L, 169L, 101L, 202L, 51L, 40L), age = c(52L, 
66L, 56L, 44L, 49L, 58L, 68L, 74L, 63L, 43L, 54L, 47L, 47L, 64L, 
65L, 57L, 59L, 46L, 59L, 66L, 73L, 54L, 54L, 62L, 54L, 47L, 51L, 
73L, 57L, 47L, 81L, 46L, 72L, 56L, 53L, 66L, 59L, 39L, 55L, 28L, 
36L, 48L, 38L, 76L, NA, 59L, 71L, 58L, 57L, 54L, 69L, 49L, 65L, 
48L, 35L, 44L, 65L, 56L, 66L, 41L, 55L, 52L, 67L, 61L, 65L, 61L, 
75L, 56L, 37L, 75L, 68L, 59L, 52L, 59L, 59L, 63L, 62L, 57L, 48L, 
65L, 41L, 60L, 77L, 66L, 50L, 51L, 81L, 61L, 64L, 48L, 63L, 78L, 
79L, 51L, 74L, 52L, 73L, 82L, 58L, 72L, 63L, 67L, 72L, 51L, 68L, 
41L, 66L, 69L, 60L, 66L, 71L, 45L, 81L, 52L, 67L, 58L, 63L, 47L, 
63L, 67L, 62L, 72L, 75L, 46L, 73L, 57L, 75L, 68L, 68L, 73L, 51L, 
59L, 59L, 60L, 54L, 62L, 64L, 48L, 73L, 79L, 58L, 46L, 75L, 63L, 
68L, 60L, 54L, 78L, 54L, 46L, 49L, 67L, 79L, 54L, 47L, 51L, 66L, 
61L, 64L, 79L, 73L, 51L, 52L, 52L, 76L, 75L, 56L, 76L, 54L, 82L, 
62L, 57L, 53L, 42L, 63L, 37L, 66L, 46L, 76L, 39L, 51L, 80L, 69L, 
76L, 48L, 65L, 59L, 76L, 57L, 66L, 69L, 68L, 72L, 62L, 56L, 51L, 
60L, 71L, 68L, 77L, 28L, 62L, 51L, 61L, 56L, 72L, 79L, 62L, 68L, 
68L, 49L, 75L, 64L, 48L, 51L, 68L, 68L, 70L, 73L, 54L, 47L, 79L, 
40L, 52L, 58L, 69L, 61L, 44L, 57L, 55L, 43L, 61L, 44L, 77L, 35L, 
74L, 72L, 60L, 44L, 53L, 61L, NA, 80L, 73L, 72L), sex = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 1L), mace = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L), mace_months_date_vs_date_sample = c(30L, 
73L, 5L, 77L, 74L, 74L, 45L, 6L, 46L, 70L, 70L, 72L, 77L, 5L, 
43L, 71L, 74L, 77L, 71L, 77L, 77L, 73L, 74L, 69L, 28L, 77L, 73L, 
68L, 73L, 70L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 69L, 69L, 78L, 69L, 58L, 78L, 71L, 
76L, 76L, 69L, 71L, 43L, 44L, 5L, 62L, 73L, 72L, 47L, 61L, 47L, 
46L, 44L, 43L, 46L, 45L, 16L, 62L, 8L, 48L, 15L, 79L, 62L, 46L, 
62L, 45L, 55L, 21L, 41L, 45L, 46L, 45L, 50L, 62L, 43L, 4L, 1L, 
4L, 63L, 17L, 3L, 45L, 2L, 50L, 1L, 44L, 15L, 46L, 46L, 7L, 8L, 
62L, 16L, 47L, 19L, 61L, 46L, 1L, 4L, 48L, 61L, 43L, 46L, 61L, 
44L, 48L, 1L, 5L, 43L, 43L, 46L, 58L, 3L, 55L, 27L, 1L, 47L, 
19L, 11L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 48L, 62L, 61L, 23L, 1L, 55L, 19L, 48L, 
1L, 43L, 47L, 1L, 46L, 11L, 46L, 48L, 46L, 32L, 50L, 61L, 62L, 
48L, 46L, 55L, 62L, 55L, 43L, 61L, 47L, 59L, 50L, 10L, 55L, 63L, 
55L, 48L, 31L, 32L, 48L, 55L, 62L, 59L, 53L, 48L, 48L, 62L, 59L, 
4L, 4L, 25L, 59L, 48L, 60L, 43L, 58L, 49L, 1L, 8L, 1L, 63L, 51L, 
55L, 47L, 49L, 55L, 49L, 55L, 13L, 60L, 2L, 13L, 3L, 25L, 7L, 
62L, 62L, 60L, 10L, 61L, 45L, 3L, 11L, 51L, 47L, 1L, 46L, 63L, 
60L, 43L, 62L, 58L, 61L, 1L, 2L, 46L, 1L, 13L, 54L, 48L, 54L, 
45L, 45L, 31L, 48L, 42L, 49L, 43L, 61L, 1L, 31L, 1L, 63L, 11L, 
47L, 39L, 7L, 42L, 1L, 1L, 1L), trop = c(2600L, 1710L, NA, 840L, 
1740L, 5010L, 776L, 7120L, 4281L, 1360L, 15300L, 6490L, NA, 15940L, 
6300L, 6020L, 2100L, 5330L, 1500L, 500L, NA, 1080L, 990L, 1420L, 
NA, 2390L, 3710L, 3340L, 180L, NA, NA, 3600L, 470L, 6390L, 1970L, 
9320L, 2260L, NA, 3930L, 6440L, NA, 4470L, 1800L, 40L, 21876L, 
871L, 7860L, NA, 320L, 8450L, 1730L, 262L, 16720L, 1247L, NA, 
NA, 54592L, 1241L, 2413L, NA, 45649L, NA, NA, 160L, 843L, NA, 
1470L, 372L, 844L, 1454L, 50000L, 11450L, 769L, 2234L, 349L, 
250L, 3654L, 8421L, NA, 5204L, 440L, NA, 40273L, 90L, 9352L, 
2177L, 10014L, 11L, 11135L, 5256L, 1753L, NA, NA, 50L, 8903L, 
3598L, 2483L, NA, NA, NA, 1557L, 5247L, 24L, 2993L, 3624L, 751L, 
NA, NA, 24160L, NA, NA, 5687L, 1911L, NA, NA, 1855L, 9951L, 13374L, 
2107L, 4927L, 83L, 2380L, 663L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1627L, 
NA, 1211L, 5654L, NA, NA, 10000L, NA, NA, NA, 2956L, 67927L, 
NA, 63L, NA, 4790L, NA, NA, 3569L, 961L, 6581L, 253L, 2888L, 
33017L, 1675L, 438L, 15543L, 6212L, 6694L, NA, 1945L, 3004L, 
3789L, NA, 2844L, 950L, 123L, 6630L, 3220L, 2040L, NA, 6672L, 
1480L, 6979L, NA, 1411L, 5711L, NA, 2340L, NA, 57L, NA, 33L, 
5110L, NA, 2797L, 1035L, 2840L, 251L, 7671L, 6155L, 4299L, NA, 
846L, 2339L, 400L, 86115L, 27L, 87355L, NA, 8669L, NA, NA, NA, 
1258L, 3000L, NA, 137L, 3866L, NA, 1312L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
2103L, 1586L, 601L, 1472L, 1692L, NA, 2102L, 6452L, NA, NA, 1244L, 
2051L, 1007L, NA, NA, NA, 1726L, 3400L, 2143L, NA, 236L, 3930L, 
31026L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5280L, 1230L), egfr = c(56L, 90L, 75L, 
71L, 71L, 68L, 90L, 78L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 77L, 83L, 52L, 49L, 88L, 
84L, 88L, 81L, 51L, 51L, 87L, 77L, 85L, 76L, 90L, 65L, 48L, 99L, 
90L, 99L, 87L, 62L, 90L, 87L, 59L, 79L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 78L, 90L, 
69L, 90L, 87L, 90L, 58L, 90L, 79L, 55L, 51L, 90L, 58L, 90L, 56L, 
62L, 86L, 61L, 84L, 63L, 63L, 90L, 90L, 85L, 64L, 67L, 45L, 90L, 
78L, 65L, 69L, 90L, 90L, 59L, 54L, 60L, 68L, 86L, 42L, 73L, 90L, 
85L, 63L, 90L, 86L, 68L, 71L, 90L, 68L, 63L, 81L, 76L, 61L, 75L, 
84L, 90L, 90L, 48L, 90L, 77L, 68L, 90L, 64L, 90L, 90L, 61L, 84L, 
80L, 69L, 58L, 65L, 86L, 86L, 46L, 56L, 90L, 46L, 87L, 84L, 68L, 
67L, 72L, 35L, 86L, 74L, 78L, 67L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 76L, 90L, 86L, 
63L, 63L, 53L, 90L, 90L, 75L, 64L, 69L, 68L, 52L, 49L, 90L, 65L, 
86L, 42L, 63L, 90L, 90L, 73L, 75L, 66L, 64L, 90L, 35L, 90L, 82L, 
90L, 84L, 61L, 90L, 86L, 51L, 52L, 69L, 54L, 90L, 75L, 85L, 72L, 
90L, 80L, 54L, 58L, 90L, 89L, 72L, 90L, 84L, 33L, 74L, 36L, 56L, 
61L, 63L, 77L, 84L, 85L, 90L, 90L, 51L, 90L, 90L, 68L, 90L, 52L, 
90L, 48L, 90L, 82L, 86L, 67L, 90L, 76L, 14L, 63L, 59L, 82L, 90L, 
39L, 77L, 90L, 78L, 74L, 54L, 36L, 58L, 69L, NA, 53L, 90L, 90L, 
90L, 88L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 63L, 87L, 48L, 90L, 55L, 70L, 
65L, 90L, NA, 90L, 90L, 72L, 66L, 55L), dm = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L), smoke = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
NA, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), delta_mon1_baseline_to_d3 = c(-821.989379882808, 
-562.289733886719, -502.216308593755, -388.549621582031, -372.002563476562, 
-308.033813476562, -283.636077880859, -279.422790527344, -218.279922485352, 
-173.209777832031, -162.939453124998, -95.700927734375, -70.961883544922, 
-69.742797851558, -69.5900268554681, -66.49755859375, -58.77816772461, 
-29.29504394531, -25.714111328125, -12.548919677734, -2.99462890625, 
2.80639648437602, 32.883270263672, 33.036499023438, 44.05969238281, 
47.6982421875, 55.87646484375, 116.716430664065, 130.585632324218, 
131.392028808594, 146.8232421875, 153.190795898438, 159.863708496094, 
164.985534667969, 179.8525390625, 180.041305541992, 192.978088378906, 
208.791275024414, 243.90209960937, 248.09851074219, 327.035522460937, 
336.011077880859, 375.086456298828, 419.108337402341, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), stratum = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4"), class = "factor"), surv = structure(c(30, 
73, 5, 77, 74, 74, 45, 6, 46, 70, 70, 72, 77, 5, 43, 71, 74, 
77, 71, 77, 77, 73, 74, 69, 28, 77, 73, 68, 73, 70, 74, 75, 76, 
69, 69, 78, 69, 58, 78, 71, 76, 76, 69, 71, 43, 44, 5, 62, 73, 
72, 47, 61, 47, 46, 44, 43, 46, 45, 16, 62, 8, 48, 15, 79, 62, 
46, 62, 45, 55, 21, 41, 45, 46, 45, 50, 62, 43, 4, 1, 4, 63, 
17, 3, 45, 2, 50, 1, 44, 15, 46, 46, 7, 8, 62, 16, 47, 19, 61, 
46, 1, 4, 48, 61, 43, 46, 61, 44, 48, 1, 5, 43, 43, 46, 58, 3, 
55, 27, 1, 47, 19, 11, 1, 1, 1, 2, 48, 62, 61, 23, 1, 55, 19, 
48, 1, 43, 47, 1, 46, 11, 46, 48, 46, 32, 50, 61, 62, 48, 46, 
55, 62, 55, 43, 61, 47, 59, 50, 10, 55, 63, 55, 48, 31, 32, 48, 
55, 62, 59, 53, 48, 48, 62, 59, 4, 4, 25, 59, 48, 60, 43, 58, 
49, 1, 8, 1, 63, 51, 55, 47, 49, 55, 49, 55, 13, 60, 2, 13, 3, 
25, 7, 62, 62, 60, 10, 61, 45, 3, 11, 51, 47, 1, 46, 63, 60, 
43, 62, 58, 61, 1, 2, 46, 1, 13, 54, 48, 54, 45, 45, 31, 48, 
42, 49, 43, 61, 1, 31, 1, 63, 11, 47, 39, 7, 42, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1), .Dim = c(245L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(
    NULL, c("time", "status")), type = "right", class = "Surv")), row.names = c(NA, 
-245L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Thank you very much for your help,

Comment: The HR and confidence interval aren't nonsense Max - they are like that because there are no events in Quartile 4. It is the modelling that is flawed. You have posted several questions about the same analysis here, and each one of them arises because you are trying to over-fit a model to too few data points. The results as you show them show no statistical difference between the quartiles, but that fact means very little in such an under-powered study. Have you considered trying a different analysis (maybe even just two groups rather than 4)?

Comment: You are right Allan. I would like to write as I have asked when the P-value is 》0.95. However, I could try to stratify by 2 groups (one with positive value, one with negative value), which means that I have to modify the quartile subgroup. Do you know how I could make that? I am very amateur in R at the moment. Thank you!

Comment: My supervisors have reported like this before so I will be asked to do it in the same way. Thank you!